# Errors when using/defining function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a JS function which parses a JSON response and displays it as a toast message. Everything works fine. I am now adding an additional feature. The JSON response is in this format:

```js
{
  "type": "message",
  "message": "Payment Approved with Order Number: &&Secure.OrderNum&& and Transaction ID: &&Secure.TransactionNum&&"
}
```

Instead of taking the whole message, I want to extract the variable value of `TransactionNum` and just display it in the HTML (so not just in the toast).

So this is the JS I wrote to extract the one value in the message object:

```js
_onDataEvent(jsonData) {
  let eventData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  // Is this a message?
  if (eventData.type === "message") {
    // Yes, show the status
    let message = eventData.message;
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Payment Status",
      message: message,
      variant: 'info'
    });
    dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

  // Is this a result?
  else if (eventData.type === 'result') {
    // Yes, show the result
    let success = eventData.success;
    let message = eventData.message;

    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Payment Result",
      message: message,
      variant: success ? 'success' : "error",
      url: "www.five9.com"
    });
    transaction(message); //I added this and VS code keeps on putting a red squiggly line on it.
    dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}

transaction(message) {
  var words = message.split(" ");
  var transactionId = words[-1];
  return transactionId;
}
```

Right now, I am getting errors on the when I am calling the method. It says

> `transaction is not defined`

When I add function keyword to the method, I then don't get the red squiggly line on the method call, but I get another error saying

> `Unexpected token: A constructor, expression, accessor or property was expected`

I am not sure how to solve this. Have I done something wrong in the
method? Is the method written correctly? Do I need to add something or
change the order?

Comment: Is this wrapped in a class, and/or is it Typescript by any chance?

Comment: `transaction(message){` is not a valid function definition, it is lacking the `function` keyword. Same for your `_onDataEvent(jsonData) {`

Comment: @Klaycon They're valid if they're prototype methods of a class, where `function myFunction()` is **not**, hence why I'm curious if this is all wrapped in a class of some sort :)

Comment: How do you get TransactionNum value? Could you some real example?

Comment: @TylerRoper ah, good catch - the error message confirms it must be in a class since it's expecting a constructor - so user needs `this.transaction(message);`

Comment: @tyler roper, I think it is typescript. As to klaycons message, ondataevent function was working fine, no problems with it (didnt put function keyword). When i put function keyword, I get the other error message.

Comment: @user3685949 It sounds like you're defining prototype methods here. Try `this.transaction(message)` instead.

Comment: putting this.transaction seems to get rid of the error. But I dont understand why I need that. I hav never called a method like that before

Comment: @user3685949 What is the context of this code? Again, it sounds like your entire snippet exists within a `class`.

Comment: These function definitions are in a class or object literal - they are not defined in any scope your code can access them with just writing something like `transaction()`. Because they are in a class (probably), they do have access to `this` - the current instance of the class the method is being run on. Since `transaction()` is being defined as a class method, you need to call it on the current instance, e.g. `this.transaction()`.

Comment: FYI `words[-1]` will always return `undefined`. Unless it has changed in some ES6+

Comment: @Thevs This hasn't changed (but note that it won't *always* return `undefined`: if you define a property called `"-1"`, it will normally access it... All non-symbol property accesses are stringified). Good catch though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is probably inside an object literal, or class declaration.

- If you omit the function keyword, you define a method on the object (not a global scope function).
- You can't use the function keyword there, as it isn't allowed.

To solve it, place the function declaration inside the `_onDataEvent` method, to create it locally:

```
_onDataEvent(jsonData) {

  function transaction(message) {
    var words = message.split(" ");
    var transactionId = words[-1];
    return transactionId;
  }

  let eventData = JSON.parse(jsonData);

  // Is this a message?
  if (eventData.type === "message") {
    // Yes, show the status
    let message = eventData.message;
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Payment Status",
      message: message,
      variant: 'info'
    });
    dispatchEvent(evt);
  }

  // Is this a result?
  else if (eventData.type === 'result') {
    // Yes, show the result
    let success = eventData.success;
    let message = eventData.message;

    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
      title: "Payment Result",
      message: message,
      variant: success ? 'success' : "error",
      url: "www.five9.com"
    });
    transaction(message);
    dispatchEvent(evt);
  }
}
```

Also, the `transaction` function does *nothing useful* in its current form:

- It does not mutate anything
- It returns a value, but the caller ignores it
- You can't access array indexes from backwards using negative numbers, it will access the `"-1"` property instead (which is usually `undefined`)

But these are off-topic for this question.

Comment: This is probably not an ideal solution, it would be easier to keep the `transaction` function as a method of the object/class and call it properly with `this.transaction(message);`

Comment: @Klaycon We don't know how `_onDataEvent` called, and as I see, it probably called from an external code. `this` might not point to the correct object, if it's called via `call()`, `apply()`, stored in a variable, or used `bind()` on it. This solution is safer, as it works in the above scenarios as well.

Comment: Good point, but in those conditions I still think I'd prefer having it outside of the class definition. Nested function definitions aren't so good for readability and maintainability

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're using your code wrapped in a class.

In this context, your this is related to the object. So if you don't use 'this' it will search just within the function context, thus giving you the error.